# selectize doesn't render inside dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm trying to use selectize.js to populate a text box from a database based on user input, but it's not rendering inside the dropdown. I'm getting the correct data from the database, but not sure how to get it to render. Maybe the JSON isn't formed correctly?

Here's the JS:

```
var $select = $('#tags').selectize({
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,
        valueField: 'PKID',
        labelField: 'TAG',
        searchField: ['TAG'],
        maxOptions: 10,
        create: true,
        render: {
            option: function (item, escape) {
                return '<div>' + escape(item.TAG) + '</div>';
            }
        },
        load: function (query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/components/nl',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    method: 'getTags',
                    tag: query,
                    maxresults: 10
                },
                error: function () {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    callback(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here's the input box:

```
<input id="tags" class="selectize" type="text" name="tags" value="" placeholder="Tags separated by commas (optional)">
```

Here's what's being returned if the person starts to type in "straw".

```
{"COLUMNS":["PKID","TAG"],"DATA":[[1475,"strawberries"]]}
```

This is exactly what it should return, but not sure why I don't see "strawberries" as a choice in the dropdown. I only see "straw" which is what I have typed.

Comment: is this code  in a coldfusion file or is `##` a typo? In `render` what would `item.TAG` be? Doesn't match anything in your returned data. Are errors thrown in console?

Comment: ## was coldfusion but I got rid of it in the question so it didn't confuse someone. No errors are thrown. item.TAG is supposed to be the value "strawberries".

Comment: `DATA` is an array of arrays, has no property `TAG` , try `item[1]` instead. Will admit I don't know selectize.js though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the code was expecting:

```
[{"PKID":1475,"TAG":"strawberries"}]
```

But I was giving it:

```
{"COLUMNS":["PKID","TAG"],"DATA":[[1475,"strawberries"]]}
```